# Sound do not work and sound test fail HP notebook

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I connected my ubuntu laptop to TV via HDMI  and played movie.  After that I disconnected and the sound do not work. I have seen the sound output is on internal speakers. But no use. I uninstalled pulseaudio . But still the issue is there. Then , i upgraded system. Still there is issue. Let me know what I can do

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please reformulate your question, is not very clear. It is the intended behavior that the output switches to Headphones (Internal speakers) when you disconnect HDMI. You shouldn't have uninstalled pulseaudio. Would be useful if you edit your question adding the output of `inxi -SA -! 31 -y 80`.

Comment: Sure, thank you for the suggestion Pablo. Here is the details. test@test-HP-Notebook:~$ inxi -SA -! 31 -y 80
System:    Kernel: 5.0.0-27-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.28.4
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Audio:     Card-1 Intel Broadwell-U Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel
           Card-2 Intel Wildcat Point-LP High Def. Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k5.0.0-27-generic

Comment: This issue is solved after killing the pulseaudio using following command killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse* . I followed the SoundTroubleshootingProcedure in the ubuntu site for it. Thanks for all the direction

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved after killing the pulseaudio using following command

```
killall pulseaudio
rm -r ~/.config/pulse/*  
rm -r ~/.pulse*
```

I followed the SoundTroubleshootingProcedure in the ubuntu site for it. Thanks for all the directions.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! If you followed some online instructions, please include a link to them in your answer. You can still add it by [edit]ing.